# Using Async / Await to count errors from 3 different loops that calls an async function on each iteration

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm new to Async/Await and Promises, but I'm not new to Callbacks.

On a node.JS server, I am trying to count errors from thousands of async calls from 3 different async functions and then i want to log the amount of errors that occurred.
I have the following function structure:

```
var sender = require('./sender');
module.exports = {
    mainFunc : function (dataObjct){
        this.func1(dataObjct.arr1);
        this.func2(dataObjct.arr2);
        this.func3(dataObjct.arr3);
    },
    func1 : function (arr){
        for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            sender.method1(arr[i]);
            //sleep for 100 seconds cause i don't want too many messages at the same time
            new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, '100'));
        }
    },
    func2 : function (arr){
        for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            sender.method2(arr[i]);
            //sleep for 100 seconds cause i don't want too many messages at the same time
            new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, '100'));
        }
    },
    func3 : function (arr){
        for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            sender.method3(arr[i]);
            //sleep for 100 seconds cause i don't want too many messages at the same time
            new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, '100'));
        }
    }
}
```

Now, `sender.method1`, `sender.method2` and `sender.method3` all seats in a different file and they all have an async call inside. For example, here is `sender.method1`:

```
method1 : function(options){
    const from = options.from;
    const to = options.to;
    const text = options.text;
    someAsyncFunction(function(err,data) {if(err) console.log(err);},from,to,text);
}
```

I would like to count all errors occurrences from `sender.method1`, `sender.method2` and `sender.method3` and log that number of errors ONLY after all async calls from all loops has finished.

**CLARIFICATION**
I know that my code is not ready to do what i want, my question is how to modify the code in order to achieve my goals. Even if it means to re-write everything in a different way.

Comment: Have you tried using Promise.all?

Comment: @user3587856 I'm having trouble understanding where to use what since the code is spread over 2 files. The async calls and the loops are not together

Comment: From every function your are just returning one promise?

Comment: @user3587856  `sender.method1`, `sender.method2` and `sender.method3` each have a single async function call with no nested async inside

Comment: the callback of your someAsyncFunction is lost; you need to synchronize, by returning a promise, or by providing a classic callback to (e.g) method1 (which has to be called upon someAsyncFunction termination). Also user3587856 noticed that in every for loop you only iterate once since you have a return in it

Comment: @user753642 sorry for the missed `return` inside the loops, that was by accident, it's only there to have control on the sending rate.
I know that my code is not ready to do what i want, my question is how to modify the code in order to achieve my goals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### synchronize your sender.methodx

by promise

```
method1 : function(options){
    const from = options.from;
    const to = options.to;
    const text = options.text;
    //ensure someAsyncFunction is a promise
    return someAsyncFunction(function(err,data) {if(err) console.log(err);},from,to,text);
}
```

or by callback (the good'ol way)

```
method1 : function(options, cb){
    ...
    return someAsyncFunction(function(err,data) {
        if(err){return cb(err)}
        return cb(null);
    },from,to,text);
}
```

I will assume you return a `promise`

#### delay your bulk

```
func1 : function (arr, oStat){
    return arr.reduce((acc, x)=>{
        //wait at least 100ms before next sender.method call
        return Promise.all([
            sender.methodX(x),
            new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100))//no need to be a string btw
        ])
    }, Promise.resolve())
}
```

#### catch your sender method error to track count

here opinionated: shared variable among methodX in order to have an idea before the termination of methodX:

```
mainFunc : function (dataObjct){
    let stats = {data1:{}, data2:{}, data3:{}};
    this.func1(dataObjct.arr1, stats.data1);
    this.func2(dataObjct.arr2, stats.data2);
    this.func3(dataObjct.arr3, stats.data3);
},
func1 : function (arr, oStat){
    oStat.count = 0;
    return arr.reduce((acc, x)=>{
        //wait at least 100ms before next sender.method call
        return Promise.all([
            sender.methodX(x).catch(e=>{
                oStat.count++;
            }),
            new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100))//no need to be a string btw
        ])
    }, Promise.resolve())
},
```

#### synchronize your mainFunc

You don't want to reproduce the non synchronizable state of `someAsyncFunction` so do not fire asynchronous stuff in the void

```
mainFunc : function (dataObjct){
    let stats = {data1:{}, data2:{}, data3:{}};
    return Promise.all([
        this.func1(dataObjct.arr1, stats.data1),
        this.func2(dataObjct.arr2, stats.data2),
        this.func3(dataObjct.arr3, stats.data3)
    ])
},
```

Comment: Great answer! However, to complete the answer, can you please point where `stats` is ready to be logged and where? I'm confused since we have a `return Promise.all` in `mainFunc`

Comment: if you only want to log it once everybody is done, you'd write it after ```Promise.all``` is fulfilled (note: ```Promise.all``` returns a ```Promise```, how do you chain promise?)

Comment: What i'm really doing with it is updating the Database (MongoDB), but my confusion comes from the `return` in the `mainFunc`, if i add more lines after that statement, it will not be executed.

Comment: except if your lines are part of the same expression. consider: ```return arr.map().concat(//this is executed)```. Same holds: ```return Promise.all().then(//this is executed)```. I have not appended new lines between the dots "." but you know you can.